# Lock Screen - Not unlocking when switching user in Ubuntu 20.04 - Is it a bug?

Tags: lock-screen, 20.04, bug-reporting

I have only one root user account. In Ubuntu 20.04, I clicked the "Lock Screen" option from the top right corner.

Once we get the unlock login screen, there is a user icon in the bottom right corner.

Upon clicking it, it takes you to the main login screen. 
There if you log in the same user it takes you back to the unlock screen login. 
If you try to unlock by entering the correct password it's not getting unlocked.

So, it only allows you to go back and forth between the lock screen and main login screen.

In the main login screen, the power off option worked and the system had to be shut down. 
Is it a bug? 
Can this be fixed? Please suggest.